# How can I cut a javascript array in half but to the nearest closing </p> or </h1> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can get it cut in half, I'm just not sure how to go about making sure half goes until the next closing block level tag.

Fake Html:

```
<div class="content-item">    
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Pellentesque nec erat diam. Donec condimentum tortor nec tellus gravida uscipit</p> 
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus</p>
</div>
```

Javascript so far:

```
var splitChar = " ";
var wordsSplit = $(".content-item").html().split(splitChar);
var wordsCount = wordsSplit.length;
var half = Math.floor(wordsCount / 2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't think you need an array for this.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate forward through the array until you hit the end or an closing block

```
i = half;
while (!wordsSplit[i++].match(/<\//) && i < wordsSplit.length);
```

Comment: Awesome. How would I limit it to certain tags though? I wouldn't want it to cut off after a </span> or </a> for example.

Comment: Modify the regexp to make it more specific, e.g., /<\/(p|div|section)/

Comment: Also, I think this solution will only work if you guarantee that there is whitespace after each closing tag.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a problem then. Thank you for the input.